# How get the second td innerHTML

Tags: javascript, jquery

**Scenario:**

I'm using datatable library to display alot of information. That table have the following rows:

```
Id   Type     Name      Case
```

What I'm looking for is that when I click the second row **Type**, that value will be taking and pasted in a textbox

Example

```
Id   Type     Name      Case
1    text     Juan       20001
3    List     Pedro      20005
```

If I click the row that has the id # 1, I need to take the Type innerHTML. Does not matter what apart of the row I click just take the second td's html.

I tried with this code:

```
$("tr td").click(function () {

    alert($(this).html());
    })
```

It worked great, But the problem is that the user have to click exactly the row Name, but would be better if user can click over any of the row and just take the second rows html.

Suggesstions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
myRow.getElementsByClassName('td')[1].innerHTML
```

should get you the `innerHTML` of the second table cell of `myRow` as long as the first table cell does not contain a nested table.

You might try adding the click handler to the rows instead of to the cells too.

Answer (score 1):

Try using eq()

> but would be better if user can click over any of the row and just
>   take the second rows html.

```
$("tr td").click(function () {
    secondrow = $(this).closest('tr').siblings().eq(1);
});
```

> If i click the row that has the id # 1, i need to take the Type
>   innerHTML. Does not matter what apart of the row i click just take the
>   second td's html.

```
$("tr td").click(function () {
    secondTd = $(this).siblings().eq(1);
    alert(secondTd.html());
});
```

Comment: add `.text()` to the end of it.

Comment: I tried and just only prints the second row's value, but all rows's values,

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
     $(function () {
        $("#thetable tr").click(function () {
           if ($(this).index() == 0) return;
           $('#tbox').val($('td:nth-child(2)', $(this)).html())
        })
     });
```

#### HTML

```
  <table border="1" cellpadding="4" id="thetable">
     <tr>
        <td>Id</td>
        <td>Type</td>
        <td>Three</td>
        <td>Four</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>4</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
        <td>5</td>
        <td>6</td>
        <td>7</td>
        <td>8</td>
     </tr>
  </table><br />
  <input type="text" name="tbox" id="tbox" />
```

It method takes into account the first row that contains only labels and doesn't set the textbox value to a label if top row is clicked.